# For loop trought id of elements with javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, for-loop

```css
#saga1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 background: rgba(255, 132, 132, 0.29);
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 font-family: verdana;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
}
#ep1 {
 margin-left: 5px;
 color: white;
 font: normal 16px verdana;
}
#ep1 li {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 5px 0 5px;
 border-top: 0.5px dashed white;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color:gray;
 padding: 2px 0 2px;
}
#ep1 li:hover {
 background:rgba(83, 3, 15, 0.29);
 color:white;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
 <div id="saga1">Bitka Bogova</div>
            <!-- toggle show/hide video on click -->
            <!-- <script src="toggleshowhide.js"></script> -->
             <script></script> // here goes the script 
                <div id="ep1">
                    <ul id="bbogova">
                      <li id="1">Epizoda 1 - Ko će dobiti 100 miliona zenija?</li>
                      <div align="center" class=1></div>
                      <li id=2>Epizoda 2 - Vegeta ide na porodično putovanje?</li>
                        <div align="center" class=2></div>
                      <li id=3>Epizoda 3 - Traži se Super Sajonac Bog!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=3></div>
                      <li id=4>Epizoda 3 - Traže se Zmajeve Kugle!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=4></div>
                      <li id=5>Epizoda 3 - Goku protiv Birusa !</li>
                      <div align="center" class=5></div>
                      <li id="6">Epizoda 6 - Ne ljutite Boga Uništenja!</li>
                       <div align="center" class=6></div>
                      <li id=7>Epizoda 7 - Vegetin razjaren preobražaj!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=7></div>
                      <li id=8>Epizoda 8 - Poslednja šansa od Birusa?!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=8></div>
                      <li id=9>Epizoda 9 - Super Sajonac Bog je rođen!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=9></div>
                      <li id=10>Epizoda 10 - Moć Super Sajonca Boga!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=10></div>
                      <li id=11>Epizoda 11 - Bitka Bogova se nastavlja</li>
                      <div align="center" class=11></div>
                      <li id=12>Epizoda 12 - Bog uništenja protiv SS Boga.</li>
                      <div align="center" class=12></div>
                      <li id=13>Epizoda 13 - Goku, nadmaši moć Super Sajonca Boga!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=13></div>
                      <li id=14>Epizoda 14 - Bitka Bogova se završava!</li>
                      <div align="center" class=14></div>
                    </ul>
```

I have more then 100 `li` elements with id's `1`,`2`,`3` and so on. Under each element is div with class's `1`,`2`,`3` and so on. 
So i want when i click on any of "li" element to show/hide it's div.
I got toggle show hide working but i can't figure it out how to do it with for loop.

I tried:

```js
var click = 1;

for(var i =0;i<=src.length;i++)
    $("#"+i).click(function() {
        if (click == 1)
            $('.'+i).html('<IFRAME SRC="'+src[i]+'" FRAMEBORDER=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=888 HEIGHT=500 allowfullscreen></IFRAME>');
        else if (click == 2) {
            $('.'+i).empty();
            click = 0;
        }

        click++;
    });
}
```

src is Array full of embed video links

*im sorry, im still learning :D *

Comment: Please post your actual code (not a picture of your code) in your question directly (not a link to it).

Comment: Using just numbers for `id` and class names is not a good idea. You should use words that describe what the `id` and/or means (numbers are OK in the word, for example: `message1`).

Comment: You need to add **all** the relevant code. The HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: If you want to store contextual data, rather than semantic or styling information, the attribute you're probably wanting for is the data- attribute. It's a much neater way than using ID, plus you can use just a number without worrying about validity.

Comment: How ironic that the OP added their code one minute before it was closed for having no code. A little later and it could have been reopened much sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id`s are irrelevant to the solution and will only complicate matters.

You simply need a way to isolate the `li` elements that will get clicked and that could be a hierarchical selector or add a class to the parent `ul`.

Also, note that your `IFRAME` string has single quotes that are out of place.

```js
var src = ["","","","","",""];

var $list = $(".toggle > li");  // Get a wrapped set of the <li> elements in the target list

// Loop over the li elements
$list.each(function(index, element){

  // Assign a click event handler to each li
  $(element).on("click", function(){
  
     // Get reference to the first div within the li that was clicked
     var $div = $(this).find("div:first-child");
  
     // Toggle the use of the hidden class on the div
     $div.toggleClass("hidden");
     
     // If the div is hidden...
     if($div.hasClass("hidden")){
       $div.html("");  // Clear the contents
     } else {
       // Populate with an iframe that relies on the index of the parent li
       $div.html("<IFRAME SRC='" + src[index] + "' FRAMEBORDER='0' SCROLLING='NO' WIDTH='888' HEIGHT='500' allowfullscreen></IFRAME>)");
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }

iframe { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Giving the parent of the li's that will be clicked a class will allow you
     to gather them up into a collection easily. -->
<ul class="toggle">
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li>
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li>
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li>
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li>
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li>
 <li>item
   <div class="hidden">surprise!</div>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: @Huangism It avoids having to set up and manage a counter and provides easier access to the element being enumerated.

Comment: but you have no counter in your code and by the vague description from the OP it doesn't sound there needs to be a counter

Comment: @Huangism Exactly. Did you read my comment. *"It **avoids** having to set up a counter..."* and so, I don't have one because none is needed. Hence, it's simpler. I'm talking about a **loop** counter.

Comment: so back to my first question, what's the point of using `each`? `$list.on()` and done

Comment: @Huangism And, back to my first answer. If a traditional `for` loop was used, you'd have to set up a counter. `.each()` in JQuery and `forEach()` in vanilla JS avoid this, which makes the code simpler and makes accessing the element being enumerated easier. Not sure what you don't get here.

Comment: You are not getting it, why add the extra code using `each` when you can just do `$list.on("click", function(){})`

Comment: @Huangism Do you not see that the each of the OP's callbacks is slightly different? You need to loop so that each element gets its own customized callback.

Comment: Yea it has access to index which you are not using, so why use `each`?

Comment: @Huangism Answer updated for clarity. The original answer was just showing how the loop would be set up because that was the specific question being asked. But, if you look at the OPs code, you can see what he wants to do in the loop besides toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0):

use your li id in onclick="function(id)" and define a variable in your javascript function to catch this id.
then use that variable wherever you want it in that function it will only change that id's property.